# Change position of "Delete <resource>" button in ActiveAdmin (Rails 3.2.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using Rails 3.2.8 with ActiveAdmin 0.4.4 .

If the `:destroy` action is enabled in an ActiveAdmin resource controller, by default, the `Delete <resource>` button appears at the top-right of the resource `show` page.

That delete button is a little too prominent and too easily clickable for my liking. I admit that there is a confirmation dialog when the button is clicked, but I would still like to re-locate the button and put it elsewhere. I would probably also make it just a small link and not style it as a button.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: To whoever downvoted the question: It is plain courtesy to let the author know what is so bad about the question that it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete action item is added in the add_default_action_items at  path/to/activeadmin_gem/lib/active_admin/resource/action_items.rb in

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class Resource
    module ActionItems
    ...
    def add_default_action_items
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

So what you could do is just wipe the delete button all together or add a specific css class to it. Not by changing the gem source, but by adding the following to the bottom of /config/initializers/activeadmin.rb and so dynamically opening up the private module method

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class Resource
    module ActionItems
      private
        def add_default_action_items
          # New Link on all actions except :new and :show
          add_action_item :except => [:new, :show] do
            if controller.action_methods.include?('new')
              link_to(I18n.t('active_admin.new_model', :model =>       active_admin_config.resource_name), new_resource_path)
            end
          end

          # Edit link on show
          add_action_item :only => :show do
            if controller.action_methods.include?('edit')
              link_to(I18n.t('active_admin.edit_model', :model =>       active_admin_config.resource_name), edit_resource_path(resource))
            end
          end

          # Destroy link on show
          add_action_item :only => :show do
            if controller.action_methods.include?("destroy")
              link_to(I18n.t('active_admin.delete_model', :model =>       active_admin_config.resource_name),
                resource_path(resource),
                :method => :delete, :confirm =>       I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation'),
                :class => 'Anjan_styles_its_own_destroy_button_class')
            end
          end
        end          
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you can style your way around, or you could just comment the whole destroy link away. The index screen still has delete links for resources. Dont forget to restart the server.

Good luck reading source!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the relevant parts of the source. That is more than enough for me to figure out where and what to customize.